Extend a function on the boundary of bounded open set in complex plane

 Lemma  Suppose that $D$ is a bounded open set in the plane. $\phi : D \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, and for every $\zeta \in \partial D$ there exists a function $\phi_\zeta$ continuous on $D \cup \{ \zeta \}$ which agrees with $\phi$ on D. Then $\phi$ extends to a function continuous on $\overline{D}$.


Proof: Extend $\phi$ to a function $\psi : \overline{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$ \psi(\zeta) = \phi_\zeta(\zeta) \ \ (\zeta \in \partial D).$$
Suppose that $\zeta \in \partial D$; we need to show that $\psi$ is continuous at $\zeta$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\phi_\zeta$ is continuous on $D \cup \{ \zeta \}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| < \epsilon$ for all $z \in D$ with $|z - \zeta| < \delta$. Suppose that $z \in \partial D$ and $|z - \zeta| < \delta$. Since $\psi(z) = \lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}} \psi(w)$ it follows that $|\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| \le \epsilon$.

I don't understand the last part, "Since $\psi(z) = \lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}} \psi(w)$ it follows that $|\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| \le \epsilon$.". How it works and why is $\le \epsilon$ instead of $ < \epsilon$?

Edit: What I've tried: Suppose that $z \in \partial D$ and $|z - \zeta| < \delta$. So, we have that $|\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| = |\phi_z(z) - \psi(\zeta)| = |\lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}} \phi_z(z) - \psi(\zeta)| = |\lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}} \psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| = |\lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}}(\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta))| = \lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}} |\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| \stackrel{\text{not}}{=} A$. \ Now, because $w \in D$ we know already from the first statement proved that $A \le \lim\limits_{\substack{w \to z \\ w \in D}} \epsilon = \epsilon$.
It's ok what I've tried? If yes... how to obtain $ < \epsilon$ instead of $\le \epsilon$??

Here is how I interpreted the solution - it comprises of two cases:

The first part is to consider $z \to \zeta$ for $z$ always inside $D$. This is just the definition of continuity at $\zeta$ and how we defined $\psi$.
Now let $z \to \zeta$ but now we only allow $z$ to be on the boundary. The strategy is that you choose another $w \to z$ for all $w \in D$ and estimate $\psi(z)-\psi(\zeta)$ using $\psi(w)-\psi(\zeta)$. This should reduce to case 1. Since we fixed $|z-\zeta|<\delta$ and $w \to z$, we can choose $|w-z|$ small enough so that $|w-z|< \delta - |z-\zeta|$. This implies $|w-\zeta|<\delta$ for all $w \in D$ and close enough to $z$. Moreover, by case 1
$$|w-\zeta|<\delta \Rightarrow |\psi(w)-\psi(\zeta)| < \epsilon$$
Thus we have
$$|z-\zeta|<\delta \Rightarrow |\psi(z) - \psi(\zeta)| = \lim_{w \in D, w \to z} |\psi(w)-\psi(\zeta)| \le \epsilon$$
Here the inequality becomes at most $\epsilon$ due to taking limit.


I think it is not necessary to get rid of the equal sign - see a discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240954/why-cant-we-assume-0-x-a-leq-delta-equality-in-an-epsilon-delta-pro
